# WizardDroid - How to replace last step with a results fragment

Tags: android

My application have  3 steps, and as the user answers the question in the last step, I'd like to replace the current view with another with some results.

I've tried to replace current fragment with results fragment, but it doesn't replace, just show below it.

Thanks for any help.

Below is just the method that is called when I click the finish button:

```
    private void bindDataFields() {  

         Fragment summaryFragment = new KitFinderSummaryFragment();           
         getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_kit_finder_q3, summaryFragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize now that the approach I was taking might not be the most appropriate.

I still don't have and answer for this, and maybe there isn't one.

The approach I decided to take is this, in case anyone stumble on similar problem: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html